# Where are Mrs. and Mr. Fowl's Butlers?

Tags: artemis-fowl

I'm a great fan of the Artemis Fowl series and I have read all the books, but one thing has always been puzzling me. In the first book, it mentions the Butlers have been serving the Fowls for centuries. However, Mr. and Mrs. Fowl never seem to have a Butler around protecting them. Do they have Butlers? If so, where are they and why do they never appear?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site ! Please consider taking the [about]. Maybe if they're not mentioned, it's because they're very good at their job ? ;) I think I remember Butlers having to be very discrete.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butler_family_(Artemis_Fowl)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mr Fowl (Artemis Fowl I) did have his own Butler bodyguard: namely **[the Major](http://artemisfowl.wikia.com/wiki/The_Major)**, Domovoi Butler's uncle. He was **killed** before the start of the series at the same time his principal was kidnapped by the Russian Mafia.

It is unknown whether Mrs Fowl (Angeline) ever had one, but certainly none appears in the series. A few years before the start of the series (when most of *AF and the Time Paradox* is set), Domovoi Butler is the only servant the Fowl family have remaining, so perhaps she did have a bodyguard who left due to not getting paid. However, it seems likely that *Butler* bodyguards were only for those who were Fowl by blood, rather than just marrying into the family.

Comment: Isn't Juliet Angeline's new Butler in the series?

Comment: @RogueJedi No, Juliet decides not to be a bodyguard and takes up wrestling instead. Until later on in the series (spoilers!), when she returns to the fold and acts as bodyguard to the twins.